# How to access POST data in express js?

Tags: javascript, express, post

Im using (in the browser):

```
  xmlHttp.open("POST", "/", true); // true for asynchronous

  xmlHttp.send("data");
```

on the client side browser.

I'm using (node js):

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log("Got a POST request");
  console.log(req);
});
```

to get the post data. but it doesn't matter what I send it doesn't show up.
I don't wanna have to install some separate "body parser" package to see the data.... I don't wanna parse it.  A post request is used to send data to the server... is the data just not there?

Comment: On the browser side, strongly consider using the modern [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't wanna have to install some separate "body parser" package to see the data.... I don't wanna parse it.

Too bad.

Even if you want to process a [plain text body](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.text) then you need to use body parsing middleware to do it.

One of the responsibilities of the middleware is to take the stream of data from the client and store it in memory (assigning it to `req.body`) instead of discarding it.

Note that body parsing middleware is installed automatically as a dependency of Express.js itself.

Comment: Why would it force you to use a parser? Is there any way to get it before its thrown away?

Comment: "Why would it force you to use a parser?" — What else is it going to do? Bloat the application by including every possible parser by default?

Comment: "Is there any way to get it before its thrown away?" — Use body parsing middleware. That is its job!

Comment: why cant it just give me access to the data directly?

Comment: I refer you to my earlier comment about bloat.

Comment: so your saying I need a parser so that the plain text my computer has received can be processed into plain text??? why would you need a parser to change data to itself?

Comment: I refer you to the penultimate paragraph of my answer. While a plain text body parsing middleware is very simple, It still needs to extract the text from the request.

Comment: I can access the data in the header without a parser

Comment: You can't … but since header formats are standard (a body could be plain text, or JSON, for URL encoded, or multipart form data, or anything) and don't have the possibility of being gigabytes in size (HTTP request body can!) and eating up vast amounts of memory and making the application fall over … Express parses headers automatically.

Comment: I think I understand a bit more, thanks for explaining ill accept your answer. but I still think express should give you access to the data parsed or not tbh.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a separate body parser library. You can use `express.json`. It
is a **built-in** middleware function in Express. You can use it like:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

You can read more about it [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

Comment: They can't use `express.json`, the data they are sending isn't JSON. They need to use `text` as per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73603009/19068) from quarter of an hour ago.